# Benchmark application for Qt?

Tags: qt, profiling, benchmarking, qtgui

I would like to do some profiling and benchmarking of Qt. The purpose of the profiling and benchmarking is to get the better understanding of Qt, and see what functions take most of the time, where are typical bottlenecks, is it rendering or some event processing, etc.

Can anybody suggest me what application to use for the benchmark? Are there any sample benchmarking applications that exploit Qt GUI? Is there anything like that that comes with the SDK?

Comment: Tried http://www.kde.org/ yet? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK comes with a bunch of examples and demo programs. The demo programs cover all the major aspects of Qt. You could use that to benchmark each of them pretty simply.

Going with larger apps (like KDE, or QtCreator itself maybe) is going to be much harder because of the complexity of the code and amount of non-Qt stuff (for KDE).

Answer (score 0):

valgrind http://valgrind.org/ is a powerful profiler

Comment: I am not looking for a profiler, but for a Qt-based application to profile.